# How will a url shortener affect search engine crawlers and social media?

Tags: url, seo, social-networking, url-shortener

I am developing and running a website that has quite a lot of likes / shares / pins / tweets on the social media sites out there, and I am now thinking of implementing a url shortener for all the permalinks of my website to make sharing easier.

Currently, when a visitor shares a post from my website, they use a link like `http://example.org/posts/long-post-title`. After I implemented my own url shortener the permalink for that post will be something like `http://ex.co/aBc123dEF`.

When a person clicks on the `http://ex.co/aBc123dEF`, my website will then redirect the visitor to the full URI.

My question and worry about implementing this is how it will affect search engine crawlers, and the social media sites out there. Let's say I have a post that has been linked a few dozen times on social sites already, and the counters on my website reflect this correctly, what will happen when I start providing the short urls?

I am worried that search engines will start seeing the short url and the long url as two different pages, and that my social media counts are also separated.

Does anyone have any ideas or experience themselves about implementing their own url shortener and how to handle my concerns?

Comment: Could you give some feedback of the answer below?

Answer (score 0):

You should not have problems because the shorter URL will do a 301 to the full URI, so you will not have problems with duplicate content, etc.

But if the link is internal so the link is a URI from your internal site i would recommend to use the full URI with a link because is better.

It the link is to external site don´t worry so much.

Anyway you will not have problems just is better use direct links that a link with a 301 or 302.